# How to get the relative paths with ls?

Tags: linux, bash, ls

I'd like to do something like this to move the last two downloaded files:

```
mv ` ls -rt ~/Downloads/ | tail -2 ` .
```

Unfortunately, `ls` only gives the filenames. How can I adapt the code above?

(Before someone points it out, I'm aware of the problems in piping the output of `ls`. I'd only use this when I know the filenames in question.)

Comment: Use `find` instead.

Answer (score 16):

Okay, so if you won't give up on `ls`, then at least try to get out of the habit of using backticks for everything, especially when `xargs` is a better fit:

```
ls -rtd ~/Downloads/* | tail -n2 | xargs -I{} mv {} .
```

Comment: Your `xargs` pleases me more than the backticks. But is there any technical reason to prefer this sequence of pipes and `xargs` over the usage of backticks or is this only a matter of taste?

Comment: In this case we're only looking at two files, but if we wanted to move thousands of files, we might accidentally try to create a command line that was too long.

Comment: Also: In the case of mere hundreds of files, we can start work immediately. With backticks, we have to wait until the entire subcommand is finished.

Comment: Also: When you manage to kick the habit of using `ls`, you can take advantage of `xargs -0`

Comment: convincing arguments to use xargs and not the backticks

Comment: either you generate the full filepath using `ls -rt ~/Downloads/*` or you prepend the directory in the `mv`command. Neither doing both nor doing none of both will work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/5982/discussion-between-miracle173-and-geocar)

Comment: Parsing `ls` is discouraged : http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: `~/Downloads/*` in the `ls` command can result in a (too) long command line because `~/Downloads/*` is expanded by the shell. If the `Downloads`-directory is empty the argument of `ls` cannot be expanded an the `mv` command will raise an error. So `ls -rtd ~/Downloads | tail -n2 | xargs -I{} mv ~/Downloads/{}` is the better choice

Answer (score 9):

You can use GNU `find` there :

```
mv $(find ~/Download -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -printf '%Ts %p\n' | sort -n | cut -d ' ' -f2- | tail -n 2) .
```

The `find -printf` options :

- `%Ts` to display the time as *epoch*
- `%p` the file path

See `man find | less +/'^ *-printf'`

**edit**

if you need to deal with spaces in file-names, I recommend this another solution :

```
find -maxdepth 1 -printf '%Ts %p\n' |
    sort -n |
    cut -d ' ' -f2- |
    tail -n 2 |
    xargs -i% mv % .
```

Comment: Added explanations on `find -printf` options

Comment: I'm curious: is there any particular reason to use `-f2-` instead of `-f2` as an option to `cut`? What's the second dash for?

Comment: Sure Francesco Turco, like said `man cut`, it prints till the end if there's more than one col.

Comment: POST edited to work with file-names with spaces.

Answer (score 3):

Use `ls -rt ~/Downloads/*`instead of `ls -rt ~/Downloads/`. In `ls -rt ~/Downloads/*` the argument string is first expanded by the shell (this is called [*filename globbing*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29)). So you get a list of paths as arguments for the `ls -rt` command, which then sorts it in the way you specify by the options of `ls`. In contrast, the command `ls -rt ~/Downloads/` reads the content of the directory `~/Downloads/`. This is a list of files without the directory path.

Answer (score 2):

With zsh:

```
mv ~/Downloads/*(.om[1,2]) .
```

The `(...)` part are called *globbing qualifiers*, one of the killer features of `zsh`. Each qualifier (usually single characters) allows to filter the matched entries based on attributes of the files (type, size, time...), alter the order in which they are expanded, or modify how they are expanded.

Above, we've got:

- `.` (dot): select regular files only (not directories, symlinks...)
- `om`: **o**rder the list by **m**odification time.
- `[1,2]`: select only the first two entries.

Also note that the command will fail if there's no match (where other shells could accidentally move the wrong file/dir).